# System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid when trying to select a Guid

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I'm fairly new to programming so please be gentle. I'm trying to store the value of 'opponent' which is a Unique Identifier in tblOrders into opponentID
Here's where I call it..

Dim opponentID As Guid = order.SelectOpponentID(orderID)

Below is the code I have tried but I get System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. If anyone can please adjust this for me I would be so grateful..

VB CODE

```
Public Function SelectOpponentID(ByVal orderID As Guid)
    Dim DBConnect As New DBConn
    Using db As DbConnection = DBConnect.Conn("DBConnectionString")
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = DBConnect.Command(db, "SelectOpponentID")

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("orderID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = orderID

        db.Open()
        Dim DR As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        Dim opponentID As Guid
        While DR.Read
            opponentID = DR("opponent")
        End While
        DR.Close()
        DR = Nothing
        cmd.Dispose()
        cmd = Nothing
        db.Dispose()
        db.Close()
    End Using
End Function
```

SQL CODE

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectOpponentID]
@orderID      uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT opponent
    FROM tblOrders
    WHERE orderID = @orderID
END
```

Comment: Is it a nullable column? Also, use `New SqlParameter("@orderID...` instead of `orderID`.

Comment: This didn't solve it but it did throw an error saying data was null like you say, so I've fixed the data and now I'm sorted thank you. I also missed out a 'Return'.

Comment: Just as a side note, using a guid as a key column in a table is a poor choice.  Any indexes on that column will likely become fragmented and will have poor query performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
opponentID = DR.GetGuid(DR.GetOrdinal("opponent"))
```

Comment: This didn't solve it but it did throw an error saying data was null so I've fixed the data and now I'm sorted thank you. I also missed out a 'Return'.